# Custom analyzer not working in elasticsearch

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, diacritics, elasticsearch-analyzers

Running elastic version 1.6

I am trying to set custom analyzer for my index in elasticsearch. My index /has some properties which contains some accents and special characters.

Like one of my property name has value like this, **"name" => "Está loca"**.
 So what I want to achieve is, whenever I am trying to search by this way,
http://localhost:9200/tutorial/helloworld/_search?q=esta

I should get the result for **"Está loca"**. I have gone through following link and configured necessary analyzer which is explain in the link.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/asciifolding-token-filter.html

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/tutorial?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"mappings":{
  "helloworld":{
  "properties": {
    "name": { 
      "type":           "string",
      "analyzer":       "standard",
      "fields": {
        "folded": { 
          "type":       "string",
          "analyzer":   "folding"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
},
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "folding": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter":  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I have configured this while creating index and made some entries like this for test,

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/tutorial/helloworld/1' -d '{ "name": "Está loca!" }'
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/tutorial/helloworld/2' -d '{ "name": "Está locá!" }'
```

but while searching like this,
http://localhost:9200/tutorial/helloworld/_search?q=esta
nothing is happening. I just want whenever a user searches in any languages for example in English it should get the same result. Please anybody can help, how can I achieve this struggling on it for last 1 week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would not be able to search for `esta` keyword in `_all` field. As elasticsearch by default only apply standard analyzer while constructing `_all` [field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html).

so your following query

```
GET folding_index1/helloworld/_search?q=esta
```

Produces following match query in elastic dsl.

```
GET folding_index1/helloworld/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": "esta"
    }
  }
}
```

Which search against `_all` field and hence couldn't find folded token for name.

You can do following, but even with `include_in_all` mentioned for multifield, it still applies standard analyzer for _all field.

```
PUT folding_index1
{
    "mappings": {
        "helloworld": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "standard",
                    "fields": {
                        "folded": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "folding",
                            "include_in_all": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "folding": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Query like following can work for you. More on [_all field analyzer](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/specifying-analyzer-for--all-field/7105/2)

```
POST folding_index1/_search?q=name.folded:esta
```

Comment: folding_index1 <- what is this? Is it my index name i.e. "tutorial"?

Comment: It is giving me following error while creating index in curl,

{"error":"MapperParsingException[mapping [helloworld]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[fielddata should be a hash but was of type: class java.lang.Boolean]; ","status":400}

Comment: yeah thats the name i used for my reference. I changed the mappings, looks like you are running a older version of elastic. I added fielddata boolean for my debugging the tokenizer. should work now

Comment: yes I am using older version I think 1.6, I will try again with the changes

Comment: Your life saviour for me, really heartiest thanks. I was working on it since last 2 weeks and was really under pressure. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This link also helped me a lot, gives exact analyzer for my scenario.

https://vanwilgenburg.wordpress.com/2013/08/03/diacritics-in-elasticsearch/

Comment: this fails on es version 5.4 for me.

Comment: Yes your right @user3775217 but the settings and mappings which the link has suggested are perfect for my scenario. Can you help me to convert the json of settings and mappings of the link, into the ES 5.4 or above supported versions. Also I have asked one quetion on stackoverflow for this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844765/elasticsearch-giving-exception-for-the-json

Comment: yes, even shay mentioned on official elastic link said, its not supported for change analyzer for _all. I was on 5.4 so i copied to _all field to a new field with custom analyzer.  Thanks

Comment: Can you provide me json for both settings and mappings in curl format from that link so that I can apply it here, I have asked one question for it this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844765/elasticsearch-giving-exception-for-the-json.  I am really struggling on it.